# why it is don't work, I use jquery. ( 1 and 2 not work )(3 and 4 work) WHYYYYY?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ejs

```
<% for (let note of listNote){ %>
      
        
    <p id="title<% note.id %>"><%= note.title%></p>

     <form action="/edit" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="updatedItemId" value="<%= note.id %>" />
      <input id="input<%=note.id%>" type="text" name="updatedItemTitle" value="<%= note.title %>" hidden="true" />
      <input type="submit" id="done<%=note.id%>" hidden="true" />
     </form>
      <input id="edit<%=note.id%>" value="edit" type="submit" onclick="handler( '<%note.id%>');"/>


 function handler(id) {
    $("title"+id).attr("hidden", true)
    $("edit" + id).attr("hidden", true) 
    $("done" + id).removeAttr("hidden")
    $("input" + id).removeAttr("hidden")
}
```

Comment: If you want to hide and show elements, use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of adding/removing attributes.

Comment: You are missing the symbol to indicate you're targeting an element by id in your jQuery. So, for example: `$("title"+id)` should be `$("#title"+id)`

Answer (score 1):

Just a small proof that toggling the attribute works perfectly fine with jquery

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  if ($('#the_input').attr("type") == 'text') {
    $('#the_input').attr("type", "hidden");
  }
  else {
    $('#the_input').attr("type", "text");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="the_input" type="text" >
<button>Toggle input type attribute</button>
```

you just need to correctly select the input elements.

i.E  `$("title"+id)` would refer to a dom-element of type title+id which would look like `<title123>`, instead you want to query for the id attribute of a dom-element of type input, e.g `<input id="123">`
Therefore use `$("#title"+id)`